# Audio comes from Speaker by default on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

The following code successfully enables speaker, but only after IBaction is triggered. I need audio to come out of speaker by default on page load. I have tried using this code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear Etc and get the same result - sound coming from the earpiece. It does however seem to work the second time the page is loaded. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
do{ 
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)

}catch{
print("problem setting the audio session to speakerphone")
print(error)

}
```